# Contact form - problem with displaying message about sent mail

Tags: php, forms, email, validation, contact

I'm trying to develop a contact form for a language school website that runs on Wordpress.
Disclaimer: I'm about 6 months into coding, so please forgive me for being new to this. I'm developing my own theme and I wanted to limit usage of plugins to bare minimum for safety reasons - I prefer to learn how to write stuff myself instead on relying on updates of a third-party plus the courses I follow on Wordpress dev listed it as a good practice to avoid unnecessary plugins.

**The problem is listed below in bold.**

What I want to achieve:

1. Simple contact form that takes following info: **name**, **email**, **course**, *phone* (optional) and a **message**.
2. Validate the form if user provided correct info - I can't make the
   user provide valid info, but at least I want to lock number into
   numbers only range and check if email is correct.
3. Check if user is human (Captcha).
4. Send the email to my address and provide a copy to the sender.
5. Inform the user whether the action was a success or a failure.

What I succeeded with:

- Mail gets sent.
- Captacha seems to be working and filtering out attempts that do not click on it.

What 'kinda works':

- The PHP doesn't seem to validate the form. I used HTML type and require instead, but I've read that solution is not ideal. I tried to use JS to write some functions that would prevent unwanted input, but I couldn't get it to work properly. I decided to ask the question first in case it might be a dead end. JS seems to be working on my Wordpress as I'm using Bootstrap and some custom JS for certain features so I'm pretty sure the code gets executed, but I wanted to ask first if that's the correct way of approach it before I invest my time in it.

**What I have a problem with:**

It is imperative to me that the user gets feedback from the page whether the email has been sent or not for obvious business-client communication reasons. I tried two solutions found on SO:

- Injecting JS alert into PHP's echo inside conditional (JS doesn't get executed)
- Using header method to redirect into thank-you.page that informs about success or error.page that
  informs about a failure and recommends another avenue of contact

**What went wrong:** the second solution got executed properly, the user gets redirected to site.com/thank-you or site.com/error, however the browser crashes due to 'too many redirects'.

I tried googling, I tried different solutions from tutorials. What would be your recommendation?

**My code:**

```
<?php 
$nameErr = $emailErr = $courseErr = $phoneErr = "";
$name = $email = $course = $comment = $phone = "";
$thank_you = wp_redirect( '"'.home_url().'/thank-you"', 301 );
$error = wp_redirect( '"'.home_url().'/error', 301 );

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
      $nameErr = "Give name";
    } else {
      $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
      // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",$name)) {
        $nameErr = "Only letters allowed";
      }
    }
    
    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
      $emailErr = "Need email";
    } else {
      $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
      // check if e-mail address is well-formed
      if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Email incorrect";
      }
    }
  
if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
  $phone = "";
} else {
  $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
  // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
  if (!is_numeric($number)) {
    $phoneErr = "Bad number";
  }
}

if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
  $comment = "";
} else {
  $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["course"])) {
  $courseErr = "Pick course";
} else {
  $course = test_input($_POST["course"]);
}
  }
 function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
  }
    if(!empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
    {
          $secret = 'mySecretKey';
          $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
          $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
if($responseData->success)
              $message = "g-recaptcha verified successfully";
              if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $to = "myEmail@mail.org"; // this is your Email address
                $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $course = $_POST['course'];
                $phone = $_POST['phone'];
                $comment = "Form submission";
                $comment2 = "Copy of your form submission";
                $message =  "Name:" . $name . "Interested in " . $course. " Number" . $phone . " " . " Wrote" . "\n\n" . $_POST['comment'];
                $message2 = "Copy " . $name ."\n\n" . "Interested in:" . $course . "\n\n" . $_POST['comment'];
                $headers = "From:" . $from;
                $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
                mail($to,$comment,$message,$headers);
                mail($from,$comment2,$message2,$headers2);
                 // sends a copy of the message to the sender
                 header($thank_you);
                // This redirects to page thanking for contact.
                }
          else 
          header($error);
// This redirects to page informing about failure.
              $message = "couldn't verify Captcha. Email not sent.";
         echo '<script type="text/javascript">mailNotSent();</script>';
     }
?>
<section id="contact" class="contact">
    <div class="container pseudonest">
        <div class="pseudonest contact__head--nest">
            <h1 class="display-5 lh-1 mb-2 contact__head--pseudocircle contact__head--header mx-auto">Enroll now</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="container m-auto">
             <div class="d-flex justify-content-center contact__form">
                <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8">
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
                            <div class="row g-3">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="name" id="nameHeader" class="form-label">Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control radio__margin" id="name" name="name"
                                        placeholder="" value="<?php echo $name;?>" required>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <?php echo $nameErr;?>
                                    </div>
                                    <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label></label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control radio__margin" id="email" name="email"
                                        placeholder="you@example.com" value="<?php echo $email;?>" required>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <?php echo $emailErr;?>
                                    </div>
                                    <label for="phone" class="form-label">Phone</label></label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control radio__margin" id="phone" name="phone"
                                        pattern="[0-9]+" placeholder="+48 111 222 333" value="<?php echo $phone;?>">
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <?php echo $phoneErr;?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col radio__col">
                                    <label for="firstName" class="form-label">Course?</label>
                                    <div class="row radio__section">
                                        <label class="radio__container">English
                                            <input type="radio" name="course"
                                                <?php if (isset($course) && $course=="English") echo "checked";?>
                                                value="English">
                                            <span class="radio__checkmark"></span>
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="radio__container">
                                            <input type="radio" name="course"
                                                <?php if (isset($course) && $course=="Polish") echo "checked";?>
                                                value="Polish">
                                            <span class="radio__checkmark"></span>Polish
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="radio__container">
                                            <input type="radio" name="course"
                                                <?php if (isset($course) && $course=="Italian") echo "checked";?>
                                                value="Italian">
                                            <span class="radio__checkmark"></span>Italian
                                        </label>
                                        <span class="error"> <?php echo $courseErr;?></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 mb-5">
                                <label for="email-content" class="form-label">Content</label>
                                <div class="input-group has-validation">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="comment"
                                        cols="30"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <form id="frmContact" action="varify_captcha.php" method="POST" novalidate="novalidate">
                                <div class="g-recaptcha my-3" data-sitekey="mySiteKey">
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" id="submit"
                                    class="btn btn-primary contact__form--btn">
                                <div id="fakeSubmit" class="btn btn-primary contact__form--btn hidden">Fill the form
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your hesitation about using 3rd party plugins, but form handling is a *primary candidate* to offload to one. That's coming from someone who always tries to build bespoke.

There is a reason why several well-established WP form plugins exist - forms are tedious to build & handle manually, prone to errors & unwittingly introducing security vulnerabilities. There are so many elements to consider & cater for.

If you still wish to pursue your own form building, I would strongly suggest using an existing PHP framework or library  (I can't recommend one personally but you can [check out a bunch on packagist](https://packagist.org/?query=form)).

It'll mean you can code your forms more expressively & less verbosely, focusing on what the form *is* rather than dealing with all the repetitive & tedious mechanics of standard form processing.

Comment: I appreciate the help. However I tried just now to create a form with WPForms and it totally broke my page. Is there any plugin that's actually safe?

Comment: @ScorpVisual WPForms is very well established & respected, can you elaborate by "totally broke [your] page?"

Comment: Basically white screen of death due to too many redirects. I tried it on localhost too and it injected some weird PHP code as text on top of the header. Removing the plugin turned the page back up.